# Sitefinity multilingual site image (not translated) issue

Tags: telerik, sitefinity

I am currently working on Sitefinity multilingual (English & Arabic) web application where I am getting a very strange issue regarding document (image) upload.

In my News module, I have a custom field for upload image. When I am adding an Arabic news of a news (translating in Arabic language of already added news of English site)  that time the image is showing the (not translated) message and the image is not showing in the Arabic site after publish. And when I select another image in that image upload field that time it's showing in Arabic site but then it's removed from English site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's happened because you need to create AR translation for image.

When you are creating Arabic translation for new, you will see:
[image]

That means your image is not translated. You need to go to `Content->Images`, find your image and add AR translation (in my screenshot it is Spanish):
[image]After that, image will appear in the Arabic site

In case, if you want different images for different languages, you can upload different image for AR translation. It is supported only in Sitefinity 9.0 and after. You need to chose `Use another file for this translation » or upload another file for this translation`. You can find more details in this documentation:
http://docs.sitefinity.com/translate-content-items-and-taxonomies#translate-an-existing-media-content-item

If you have older version of Sitefinity, you can check this article: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-localize-media-content

Comment: Thanks @victor, but can we do this from the add/edit form itself without going to Content > Images?  As if we have 1000 images for 1000 news that time it's very difficult to open each and every image do this right?

Comment: I published small repo https://github.com/vleontyev/sitefinity-image-auto-translation It will help you automatically translate newly published images to all another languages